# Retrieve where clauses in CodeIgniter Activerecord

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is there a way to retrieve what the "where" clauses i have added in my query?
I use a foreach statement to add the columns I want to add in the where clause for the current query but, since the clause could be empty (no columns added, 0 iterations in the foreach) the query would retrieve all the records in the database because no restrictions where made.
Of course I could use a boolean variable to know wheter the foreach is making at least 1 iteration but I would like to know whether it is possible to retrieve information related to the query i'm making.
Sorta the code i'm using:

```
foreach($columns as $column => $value){
    if($column!=''){
        $this->db->where($column,$value);
    }
}
$this->db->get('mytable');
```

Some explanation:

If $column is an emptry string i don't add it to the query.

$columns var is an object (stdClass).

So, if there is no "where" statement in the query, I don't want to retrieve any information with $this->db->get(). What I'm looking for is something like

```
if( ! empty($this->db->where_clauses()))
    $this->db->get('mytable');
```

Is there something like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly: its a bit of a hack, but you can do this:

```
if( ! empty($this->db->ar_where))
```

Try that and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach($columns as $column => $value){
    if($column!=''){
        $this->db->where($column,$value);
    }
}

if (count($columns) > 0)
$this->db->get('mytable');
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. Take another look at the question. Counting the columns will do nothing in the case that all indexes are equal to an empty string. See here: http://ideone.com/Sfs8I

Comment: Wait a minute, he said: "want to add in the where clause for the current query but, since the clause could be empty (no columns added, 0 iterations in the foreach)". If there are zero iterations it means its count is 0.